# Replace function with wildcard

Tags: vba, excel, replace, wildcard

Currently I have developed an operation tool which compares complex engineering source files of a DCS. Therefore I have to replace certain 'TagNames'.

The code where the replacing applies:

```
    For g = 8 To amountofreplace 'replace the string with every potential transition
            With Sheets("Compare")
                orgi = .range("L" & g).Value
                copy = .range("J" & g).Value
                tmp_string = Replace(tmp_string, copy, orgi)
             End With
```

An example would be
tmp_string = 200TT-50 or 200TX-50 or 200GG-50

This should be transititioned to 350TT-50 or 350TX-50 or 350GG-50

So right now I would add the transitions
200TT --> 350TT
200TX --> 350tx

But what I would prefer is to appy this transition
200$$ --> 350$$

$ would mean a character [A-Z] So that when it gets applied it will directly apply all the transitions I mentioned above.

Wildcard does not work with Replace function.. Who has a clue? Because I will fill in different transitions all the time. So Regex doesn't seem like a solution to me.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: why do you think regular expression doesn't work for you? indeed you can't change the case with it, but you can find the lower case letters, change case with `uCase()` and replace it to the original string as you do it now. (`tmp_string=Replace(tmp_string, RegExResult, uCase(RegExResult))` where RegExResult is the lower case letter find by regular expression search)

Comment: It isn't cleat what your question is. Replace(tmp_string, "200","350",1,1) will change any 200$$ to 350$$ irrespective of what $$ is. Forget about regular expressions -- you haven't even explained why you would even need wildcards in the Replace function.

Comment: expanding on my previous comment: for strings of length at least 5, what is the difference between "apply the transition 200$$ --> 350$$" and "apply the transition 200 --> 350"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA.Left() like in

```
If VBA.Left(tmp_string, 3) = "200" then 
    tmp_string = "350" & VBA.Right(tmp_string, Len(tmp_string)-3)
end if
```

Comment: I assume the lowercase letters are a typo, though